# jQuery TinySort sorting and placing by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a Friday afternoon moment, and I'm really struggling to sort these items how I want to!

I have a list that will be filtered by choosing from two drop down lists. One is for the attribute, the other is for the value. I then want to sort the list based on the two drop down lists.

So for example, the user might select attr4 with a value of 30. I then want to sort the list in ascending order with the matching items first, followed by the unmatched items. I.e. this list below:

```
<ul>
    <li data-attr1="10" data-attr2="20" data-attr3="30" data-attr4="40" data-attr5="50">Option 1</li>
    <li data-attr1="20" data-attr2="30" data-attr3="40" data-attr4="50" data-attr5="10">Option 2</li>
    <li data-attr1="30" data-attr2="40" data-attr3="50" data-attr4="10" data-attr5="20">Option 3</li>
    <li data-attr1="40" data-attr2="50" data-attr3="10" data-attr4="20" data-attr5="30">Option 4</li>
    <li data-attr1="50" data-attr2="10" data-attr3="20" data-attr4="30" data-attr5="40">Option 5</li>
</ul>
```

Would then look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-attr1="50" data-attr2="10" data-attr3="20" data-attr4="30" data-attr5="40">Option 5</li>
    <li data-attr1="10" data-attr2="20" data-attr3="30" data-attr4="40" data-attr5="50">Option 1</li>
    <li data-attr1="20" data-attr2="30" data-attr3="40" data-attr4="50" data-attr5="10">Option 2</li>
    <li data-attr1="40" data-attr2="50" data-attr3="10" data-attr4="20" data-attr5="30">Option 4</li>
    <li data-attr1="30" data-attr2="40" data-attr3="50" data-attr4="10" data-attr5="20">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

I can do the entire list sorted quite easily using:

```
$('ul li').tsort({ data: attribute, order: 'asc'});
```

but I'm having trouble getting the matched items infront of the unmatched ones. I tried using:

```
$('ul li').tsort({ data: test, order: 'asc', place: 'start' });
```

to no avail. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated - have a great Friday! Thanks!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.

The simplest way would be to split the list into two lists, first with items that match your spec (and thus go first) and second with items that don't.  Sort each list as you like, and then join them to overwrite the original.

A second way, which is more complicated but would sort the list in-place, requires you to write a custom sort function:

```
$('ul li').tsort('', { sortFunction:function(a,b) {
    var amt, bmt;

    amt = matchesSpec(a);
    bmt = matchesSpec(b);
    if (amt || bmt) {
        if (amt && bmt) {
          // Both match spec, so equal
          return 0;
        }
        // Only one matches spec; the one that matches is always less to go first
        return (amt ? -1 : 1);
    }

    // Neither matches spec, do normal comparison
    return normalCompare(a, b);
}});
```

matchesSpec would return true if the combobox attribute matched the list item.  normalCompare would return 0 if the items were equal in the sort order, -1 if a should come first, and 1 if b should come first.  If TinySort has a default function that is callable, you could also use that.

Comment: I ended up not using TinySort and going for your first option of splitting the one list into multiple arrays, sorting them how I wanted and then concatenating them before replacing the list items. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.suites li').each(function() {
    if($(this).data(attribute)==0) {
        resultsZilch.push($(this));
    } else if($(this).data(attribute)>=amount) {
        resultsMatch.push($(this));
    } else {
        resultsClose.push($(this));
    }
});

resultsMatch.sort(normalCompare);
resultsClose.sort(normalCompare).reverse();

var resultsTotal = resultsMatch.concat(resultsClose, resultsZilch);

$('ul li').remove();

$.each(resultsTotal, function(index, item) {
    $('ul').append(item);
});
```